# Why is there a one-second timestamp difference on copy?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, timestamp

I periodically copy a folder from my Ubuntu 12.04 laptop to a removable USB flash drive, using the Ubuntu file system (i.e. Nautilus 3.4.2) to drag the folder from one window to the other.

It then copies the files and asks me questions about whether I really want to overwrite, first asking about the folders, and then about the files...

**When it asks about the files, it shows the first file it is thinking of overwriting, but it is a file that has not changed since I first copied it to the flash drive**. **It shows the same size but the timestamp is one second different between the two**, for some reason. I tell it to go ahead and overwrite all such files, because I do want it to get the latest versions of files which have actually changed.

I would prefer it to only copy the files that are actually different, but I don't see how to do this, and it seems silly/wrong that the time is off by a minute on files which have not changed.

Why does this happen, and is there anything I can do about it? Is it a problem with the flash drive? Do I need to switch to using some other software to do this?

Edit: The difference is one second, not one minute, and the date isn't being updated to the copy date when I make these copies - the first file is a PDF I have never changed, and the date is from back in 2012 when I downloaded it, just one second off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't fear the terminal you could write a small shell script which copies your files periodically. Use cron to run the script for example every 15 minutes.

```
#!/bin/sh

source=/path/to/your/source/folder
target=/media/your/usb/drive

sudo rsync --verbose --recursive --update --human --progress $source $target
```

Then create an cron entry with crontab -e

Check these links for detailed information:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ManXamples/rsync

http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Comment: Thanks! Looks like --update will avoid the extra copies. I still wonder why the file timestamps are off, though. (FYI, seems like the first link is to an incomplete page, and the second and third links are the same as each other.)

Comment: Yeah you are right. I updated the links. The first is okay to be incomplete because you just need the first example. I don't know how deep your knowledge of unix is but I'll try to explain why timestamps are different.

Ubuntu stores 3 types of timestamps about files (access, modify, change). When you copy a file you change the inode information (this contains information about where a file is stored on a disk). This updates the timestamps. So Nautilus thinks the copied file is newer (Nautilus does not compare contents). With rsync you can compare contents.

Comment: Ok, so this date (the modified date, it says) has some amount added to it to encode location information, which results in the date always being off by a second between these two locations? And Nautilus (the default file system utility for Ubuntu) gets fooled by this standard practice and so thinks all these files are different? But rsync is smart enough to not be fooled by this?

Comment: Yep. Because Nautilus just evaluates the timestamp and sees that the timestamp on the flash drive is a newer one than the one from the source (Which could occure due to cached read and write operations). but rsync is able to compare the contents by creating checksums of both files (See -c parameter of manual page for rsync for more details)

Comment: I have the same problem, but not the technological knowledge to understand the solution you are all describing. Can you put it in laymen's terms so that I can fix mine as well?